# Why does RelativeSource binding randomly fail to find source?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I need someone to explain to me why two bindings randomly fail to find the binding `Source`.   They switch between failing and working even when I precisely repeat the exact same 2 steps over and over:  (Start app, Navigate to page.  Start app, navigate to page, etc).     I might get 5 failures in row, then it works, then fails 7 more times, then works twice, etc.

Here is what "failure" looks like in the VS output window

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='MyCompany.Controls.LayerView, AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=ScanHeight; DataItem=null; target element is 'Path' (Name=''); target property is 'Data' (type 'Geometry')
System.Windows.Data Warning: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='MyCompany.Controls.LayerView', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=ScanWidth; DataItem=null; target element is 'Path' (Name=''); target property is 'Data' (type 'Geometry')
```

Here are the bindings.  I want to use properties of the control containing the binding, so I use `RelativeSource FindAncestor`

```
<ctrl:LayerView x:Name="MainLayerView">
    <ctrl:LayerView.Layers> 
        <Path>
            <Path.Data>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CvtGuideOption}">
                    <!-- These fail to find the LayerView, but only *sometimes* -->
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ctrl:LayerView}}" Path="ScanHeight"/>
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ctrl:LayerView}}" Path="ScanWidth"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </ctrl:LayerView.Layers>
</ctrl:LayerView>
```

I could live with these always working or never working, but *randomly*? (I tried using `ElementName` instead of `RelativeAncestor` binding but the effect was the same.  Random.)

Finally, I stumbled upon an approach (below) that seems to get around this.  But I don't know if I can trust it.

```
<ctrl:LayerView x:Name="MainLayerView">
    <ctrl:LayerView.Layers>
         <Path Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ctrl:LayerView}}}">
            <Path.Data>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CvtGuideOption}">
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Tag.(ctrl:LayerView.ScanWidth)"/>
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Tag.(ctrl:LayerView.ScanWidth)"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </ctrl:LayerView.Layers>
</ctrl:LayerView>
```

As you can see, my hack is to first bind the `LayerView` source into a the `Tag` of the `Path` and then use ***that*** as the source of the individual bindings.  So far, this appears to always find the source.

But to be sure I've fixed the problem I need to understand what it was.

About the only WAG I can make is that this is somehow related to the nature of the `Layers` collection I'm filling out.  It's not a `DependencyProperty`.  I'm trying to mimic what `ItemsControl.Items` does. Could that be a factor?

**Additional Info:** The `LayerView` control looks like this.  It's large so I've shown only the relevant bits here.

```
// Custom control with a collection of layers and two Dependency properties.

public class LayerView : MultiSelector
{         
    // Layers property is not a DependencyProperty.  Just a public
    // Collection of objects.  This is me trying to mimic how ItemsControl 
    // implements its "Items" property  
    private Collection<object>? _layers;
    [Bindable(true), Category("Content")]
    public Collection<object> Layers => _layers ??= new Collection<object>();


    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScanWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(ScanWidth),
            typeof(double),
            typeof(LayerView),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                2464.0, // Default width from camera
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public double ScanWidth
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(ScanWidthProperty);
        set => SetValue(ScanWidthProperty, value);
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScanHeightProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(ScanHeight),
            typeof(double),
            typeof(LayerView),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                2056.0, // Default image height from camera
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public double ScanHeight
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(ScanHeightProperty);
        set => SetValue(ScanHeightProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: <Binding ScanHeight, RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={local:LayerView}}"/>
Wouldn't that work? (assuming the xmlns is local)
(that might not answer directly your question but can lead you to ideas)

Comment: `LayerView` is not local.  It lives in another xmlns named "ctrl"